# Octopress generate posts with bulleted list but pages without bullets

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, markdown, octopress

I generate a new post

```
rake new_post["Test bullet"]
```

I then generate a new page

```
rake new_page["PageTestBullet.md"]
```

Then I add the following to both markdown files

```
## Example 1


* vegetables
    + brocolli
    + chard
    + [Test bullet](/pagetestbullet.html)

## Example 2

1.  one
2.  two
3.  three
4.  [Test bullet](/pagetestbullet.html)
```

Then I generate the site

```
rake generate
```

and preview it

rake preview

The post display with bullets

[image: post with bullets]

The page without bullets

[image: page without bullets]

How to make they appear?

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared the CSS for list items on pages and posts to make sure different styles aren't being applied?

Comment: I can't find where to look at

Comment: You can use a tool called Firebug to see what CSS is being applied to your HTML from within your browser. [link to Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Are you using a custom Octopress theme? I replicated your test with the default Octopress theme and bullets appeared on the page and the post.

Comment: I was thinking it is theme issue you confirmed, I am using [firefox](https://github.com/sevenadrian/foxslide) theme